# What is the best TERM type on AIX for use with PuTTY, and which PuTTY settings should be tweaked?

Tags: putty, aix, xterm, term

I manage many AIX machines, generally version 5.3.

Basic terminal function works just fine, but it seems like some things don't. For example `nmon` displays `lqqx` instead of the line drawing characters.

```
lqnmonqqqqqqqqr=ResourcesqqqqqqqqHost=sigloprodqqqqqqRefresh=2 secsqqq11:29.
1 Memory qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqx
x          Physical  PageSpace |        pages/sec  In     Out | FileSystemCx
x% Used       97.4%      1.3%  | to Paging Space   0.0    0.0 | (numperm) 5x
x% Free        2.6%     98.7%  | to File System    0.5    1.5 | Process   2x
xMB Used    7980.3MB    26.2MB | Page Scans        0.0        | System    1x
xMB Free     211.7MB  2021.8MB | Page Cycles       0.0        | Free       x
xTotal(MB)  8192.0MB  2048.0MB | Page Steals       0.0        |           -x
x                              | Page Faults       3.0        | Total    10x
x------------------------------------------------------------ | numclient 5x
xMin/Maxperm     781MB( 10%)  3904MB( 48%) <--% of RAM        | maxclient 4x
xMin/Maxfree     248   1088       Total Virtual   10.0GB      | User      7x
xMin/Maxpgahead    2    128    Accessed Virtual    3.2GB 31.8%  Pinned    1x
x                                                                          x
xqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqx
x                                                                          x
x                                                                          x
x                                                                          x
x                                                                          x
mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
```

I am currently using the `xterm` terminal type on AIX, specifying utf8 encoding in putty, Using unicode line drawing code points in putty, and using the Deja Vu Sans Mono font, which should include all line drawing characters

`nmon` does display correctly when I run it from an xterm on that same machine.

Current terminfo entry for `TERM=xterm` is as follows:

```
sigloprod ~ $ echo $TERM
xterm
sigloprod ~ $ infocmp
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/lib/terminfo/x/xterm
xterm|vs100|xterm terminal emulator,
    am, km, msgr, xenl,
    cols#80, it#8, lines#25,
    batt1=f1, batt2=f1md, bel=^G, bold=\E[1m,
    box1=lqkxjmwuvtn, box2=lqkxjmwuvtn, civis=\E[?25l,
    clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?25h, cr=\r,
    csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=\b,
    cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\n, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
    cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
    cvvis=\E[?25h, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
    dl1=\E[M, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, font0=\E(B, font1=\E(0,
    home=\E[H, ht=\t, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@, ich1=\E[@,
    il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=\n, kbs=\b, kcub1=\E[D,
    kcud1=\E[B, kcuf1=\E[C, kcuu1=\E[A, kdch1=^?,
    kf1=\E[11~, kf10=\E[21~, kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~,
    kf2=\E[12~, kf3=\E[13~, kf4=\E[14~, kf5=\E[15~,
    kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~,
    khome=\E[H, kich1=\E[2~, knl=\r, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
    ktab=\t, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, nel=\n, rc=\E8,
    rev=\E[7m, rf=/usr/share/lib/tabset/vt100, ri=\EM,
    rmcup=\E[?7h, rmkx=\E>, rmso=\E[m, rmul=\E[m$<2>,
    rs1=\E>\E[1;3;4;5;6l\E[?7h\E[m\E[r\E[2J\E[H, sc=\E7,
    sgr=\E[%?%p1%t;7%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p3%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p6%t;1%;m%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;,
    sgr0=\E[m\E(B, smcup=\E[?7h\E[?1l\E(B\E=, smkx=\E=,
    smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m$<2>, tbc=\E[3g,
```

Comment: What are your settings in PuTTY under Window>Translation?

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Still no output. It seems apparent that NO termino entries here have the acsc capability.

Remember, using the xterm program as the emulator does work fine with TERM=xterm.  The output to putty with TERM=xterm should be working too!

Comment: Did you look for the box1 and box2 capabilities in each terminfo file?

Comment: What happens with good-ol' VT100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Putty's Configuration menu: Window -> Translation -> Received data assumed to be in which character set -> UTF-8

If UTF-8 isn't it, try some of the other values.

Comment: Turns out setting it to ISO-8859-1 works!  I presumed the remote end was sending escape codes to put the terminal in line drawing mode, then sending the alternate character set `lqqk` for line drawing (http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/table5-13.html)... and adjusting PuTTY shouldn't change that aspect of emulation. But I guess PuTTY ignores that when set to UTF-8 and looks for line drawing characters ONLY as unicode code points. Browsing the PuTTY 0.6 source seems to verify this at line 2573 of TERMINAL.C

Comment: Agreed.  Setting to ISO-8859-15 (euro) works here.

Answer (score 2):

Try `$export TERM=dtterm` this gives you some colors as stated in official FAQ. 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/wikiptype/nmon+faq / Question 41

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem but when remoting into Debian machines. As stated by @scott Putty ignores the sequence to change to drawing lines mode when in UTF-8. What has worked for me was telling putty to identify it self as 'putty' terminal instead of 'xterm', change 'Connection > Data > Terminal-type string' option to putty 'putty'.

[image: fix line drawing in Putty or Kitty]

Answer (score 0):

Putty may have changed, but when I selected "Allow ACS line drawling in UTF," feature in the window -> translation, it works.

Comment: This fixes `nmon` line-drawing on a Linux host for me with KiTTY 0.70.0.1p, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**

Aix uses two capabilities called **box1** and **box2**. Try modifying the commands below to look for them instead of **acsc**.

**Previously:**

Try this command:

```
for t in $(find /lib/terminfo -type f -print); do echo; echo -n "$t "; tput -T$(basename $t) acsc; done
```

or:

```
for t in $(find /lib/terminfo -type f -print); do echo $t; infocmp $(basename $t)| grep acsc; done
```

Replace "/lib/terminfo" with the path to your terminfo files. Look for lines that **do not** look like this:

> ``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~

One of those terminals has a good chance of working for you.

You can set that terminal type using `TERM=termtype` at a Bash prompt or in your `~/.bashrc` or by doing this:

```
TERM=termtype nmon
```

To have it set only for that invocation. If you'd like to set it for an `ssh` session from the local end, you can do:

```
TERM=termtype ssh ...
```

if `AcceptEnv` in the remote system's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is set to allow it. And `SendEnv` in the local system's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` or the user's local `~/.ssh/config` is set to send it.

Comment: I am reluctant to add entries to the systemwide terminfo or termcap files, or to include files in my home directory or login scripts, because it's a collection of a dozen or more machines who's 'customization complexity' I want to keep to a minimum (and it would take weeks to roll systemwide changes through change control,  assuming they were even permitted.)

Comment: 1.)  -printf is not a valid option to find on this AIX.  2.) xterm meets the above criteria and is not currently working properly.

Comment: I modified the command to use `basename` instead of `printf`.

Comment: Syntax still incorrect; i added the hyphen to the `-type` option to find. No output produced.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but what are your remote system's `$LANG` and `$LC_ALL` Bash variables set to?

Comment: "No output produced" Did you check to make sure that the path in the `find` command is correct? It is sometimes in `/usr/share/terminfo`. Does `tput -Txterm acsc` produce "``aaffgg..."?

Comment: I understood the original intent of your commands and made them work before I posted a reply.  The original path is correct. "No output produced" means I got my shell prompt back without any intervening output. 

tput -Txterm acsc produces nothing.  And there is no acsc capability in the infocmp output.

Comment: LANG=C, LC_ALL is unset.

Comment: Presumably if this AIX had a UTF-8 locale, using it would have fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try setting TERM=xterm

Comment: Term type is already set to `xterm` as stated in question.